# How to write Russian/Unicode characters in nano/vi editor

Tags: unicode, vi, nano

How do I get Russian letters to show up properly when using nano?
Currently they show up like this:

�^��^�новн�^�е

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are asking about vi or nano?  They are two different editors.

Comment: what's `locale` say? nano just uses the encoding set in your terminal. What are you using for your terminal emulator?

Comment: thanks meatspace, that was what the problem was: added sudo locale-gen ru_RU
sudo locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8 now everything works